# Graph multi-day data on a time series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, data-visualization

I have a table consisting of (timestamp, integer) where the timestamps comprise readings over multiple days. I want to use this data to plot multiple time series on one graph such that it shows the progression of readings over the course of a day. That is,
x-axis: times from midnight to 11:59 PM
y-axis: first line graph containing readings from 2nd july; second line graph containing readings from 3rd July etc.

[image: example data here]

Is there an easy way to do this in Excel? I have thousands of data points so I prefer not to do this manually.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to create the PivotChart and Grouped by Days and Hours:

[image]